# Trouble running maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

[image]

I have trouble running the project imported in maven.
I followed the following steps  ->
**go to Open File...→Import Project from File System, then choose your project1 directory. To compile your project, right click on the project name at the Package Explorer, select Run As, and then Maven install.**

I get the error as shown in the pic.....I have installed jdk 1.6 though...any way how to resolve this???

Here's the complete pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>edu.uta.cse6331</groupId>
 <artifactId>cse6331-P1</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>0.1</version>
 <name>CSE6331 Project #1</name>


<properties>
  <hadoop.version>2.6.0</hadoop.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Without details about the project and the `pom.xml`, it is hard to help you.

Comment: in the pom.xml file, there's a error stating missing artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6.   If that's of any help

Comment: Please edit the question and add the complete pom.

Comment: You've installed JDK 1.6, but is it *using* that JDK to run Maven?

Comment: Yes................

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Also ensure you refer to correct to JDK location not JRE (${java.home})

Please check eclipse is referring to JDK and not JRE.

```
In Eclipse, Navigate to Window -> Preferences
```

On the left hand pane, expand Java and you will find the `"Installed JREs"` entry